# How to change something in the code according to settings in the GitLab CI build script

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, continuous-integration, gitlab

My code is written in C++
GitLab CI Compiler: MSVC2017_x64

My project is being compiled with a GitLab pipeline on a Windows server. I want to be able to compile parts of this project two times and somehow change something in the code, before it is compiled so that I will have two versions of the same application but with different predefined settings.
Something simple like the compiler setting a `#define` in a header or cpp file would be great.
Using this same technique, I'd also like to hard wire the build number (pipeline ID) into the application.

I've already tried the `/D` or `-D` parameter but it doesn't set a `#define`.

The solution needs to work no matter what the user's setup is so something like environment variables won't work.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (the application is ultimately built with the `qmake` and `nmake` calls):

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - windows
    - qt
  script:
    - call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
    - call "C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qtenv2.bat"
    - set CL=/MP16
    - set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5";%PATH%
    - cd %CI_PROJECT_DIR%\(...)\Application
    - qmake CONFIG+=release
    - nmake
    - cd %CI_PROJECT_DIR%\(...)\3rdParty\Windows
    - copy (...)\Application.exe .
    - copy (...)\Application.ico .
    - windeployqt .
    - iscc InnoScript.iss

  artifacts:
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
    expire_in: 1 month
    paths:
    - (...)\3rdParty\Windows\Application.exe
```

And this is how I would want it to be (with the `-D mode=xy`'s):

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - windows
    - qt
  script:
    - call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
    - call "C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qtenv2.bat"
    - set CL=/MP16
    - set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5";%PATH%
    - cd %CI_PROJECT_DIR%\(...)\Application
    - qmake CONFIG+=release
    - nmake -D mode=prod
    - qmake CONFIG+=release
    - nmake -D mode=stage
    - cd %CI_PROJECT_DIR%\(...)\3rdParty\Windows
    - copy (...)\Application.exe .
    - copy (...)\Application.ico .
    - windeployqt .
    - iscc InnoScript.iss

  artifacts:
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
    expire_in: 1 month
    paths:
    - (...)\3rdParty\Windows\Application.exe
```

> How do I modify my code by only using the GitLab CI or is there another, better way?

Comment: If you use `qmake` you probably have a .pro file? If so, you might use two .pro file, one per configuration, and build two versions of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out how to do it.

Before, I was trying to add the `-D` argument to the `nmake` call when instead, I needed to add a `DEFINES+=MY_VAR='foo bar'` to the `qmake` call.
After doing this and deleting the `build-` folder to get rid of the outdated `Makefile.Debug` and `Makefile.Release` files I got it to work correctly.